# passing data between server and client (node.js + mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I'm working with node.js express and mongodb, I have a input data from client, I need to pass the data to server look for its property and send to the client in another page.

Now I have problem with    `req.body.age` that suppossed to get the data from client's input and use `find()` to get its appropriate property.

**Server side code:**

functions are routed in another .js file

```
exports.find_user = function(req, res) {
    res.render('find_user.jade');
};


exports.user = function(req, res){
    member = new memberModel();
    member.desc.age = req.body.age; //problem
    console.log(req.body.age);  //undefined 
    memberModel.find({desc: {age: '7'}}, function(err, docs){
        res.render('user.jade', { members: docs });
    console.log(docs);
});
};
```

`memberModel.find({desc: {age: '7'}}` just hardcode picking up user with age 7 (works)

**client side code (jade):**

page for data input:

find_user.jade

```
form(action='/', method='post')
    fieldset
        lable(for="age") Find user by age: 
            input(type="text", size="30", name="age", required="required")
            input(type='button', value='Find', onclick='location.href=\'find_user/user/\'')
```

page for data output with its property:

user.jade

```
        tr
            th Name
            th Age
    tbody
    - members.forEach(function(member){
        tr
            td= member['name']
            td= member['desc']
     - });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not submitting your data in find_user.jade file when the user clicks the button. Instead, the client is only redirected to another page.

This is how your find_user.jade file should look like:

```jade
form(action='find_user/user/', method='post')
    fieldset
        label(for="age") Find user by age: 
            input(type="text", size="30", name="age", required="required")
            input(type='submit', value='Find', name="submit")
```

Comment: I still get undefined when i `console.log(req.body.age)` and Cannot POST /find_user/user

Comment: Please show me the file in where you handle your routes, then. It is making a POST request to /find_user/user instead of a GET request, so it might be that your routes do not accept POST requests correctly.