# How can I extract a form's data at the server?

Tags: html, node.js, web-applications, express

I have a form and want to submit its contents to the server on submission.I found a similar question here[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793860/passing-data-between-server-and-client-node-js-mongodb) which suggests using a POST request but I am not sure how to do that.
Here's my code
Client side:

```
<form method='post' action='http://localhost:8080' >
  <textarea id='chatHistory'></textarea>
  <br/><br/>
  <div class="demo">
   <div class="ui-widget"> 
    <input id="tags" size="50" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" style="height:40px;width:120px;font-size:18px;" />
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Server Side:

```
app.post('/', function(req,res)
{
  // create reusable transport method (opens pool of SMTP connections)
  var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "my_mail_id@gmail.com",
      pass: "password"
    }
});

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
 from: "Suggestion Box ✔ <my_mail_id@gmail.com>", // sender address
 to: "receiever@gmail.com", // list of receivers
 subject: "Hello ✔",
 text: req.chatHistory.value
};
// send mail with defined transport object
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
 if(error){
     console.log(error);
 }else{
     console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
 }
});
});
```

The body of the mail is not getting filled with the value from the client.I think the problem is here:req.chatHistory.value

How can I get the chatHistory value at the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you never call `req.param("myparam");`

Try:

```
var chatText = req.param("chatHistory");
```

Then, pass it to the mail function:

```
text: chatText
```

**ps:**

```
<textarea id='chatHistory' name='chatHistory'></textarea>  //add name param
```

same with:

```
<input id="tags" size="50" type="text" name='tags' />   //add name param
```